# Java dynamically wrap parameters into an object?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

In Java, especially in Spring, how to dynamically create an object instance?

```
String fld =  "objAList[4].objB.objCList[5].name";
String fld1 = "objAList[3].objB.objCList[4].name";
String fld2 = "objAList[4].objB.objCList[4].name";
String fld3 = "name";
String fld4 = "objDList[4].name";
String fld5 = "objDList[4].objB.objCList[6].name";
```

Think about it as two dimension array, the first column for objAList, the maxium index is 4, then we need to create 4 instances to that array. For objeAList[4].objB, the objCList max index is 5, so create 5 instances to the array.

It is mainly for wrapping the http request parameters into an object. Similar to Struts Dynamic Form Beans.

How to do it? Do we have any existing library for this?

Comment: Please add more specifics to your question. If you want to dynamically inject your beans to a custom Java object, you can easily do that by adding <property> in dispatcher-servlet.xml. On the other hand, if you want to convert your incoming request to Java bean, Jackson is a great tool for JSON- Java bean mapping.

Answer (score 0):

May [JSON-XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html) could be an good start....